# Wrapping long tag names in question list

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags, design, question-lists

I know this isn't a big deal, but I thought I'd bring it up anyway.

When a question has a particularly long set of tags, it causes the user name to drop below the tag list:
[image: Ugly long tags]

This is a bit ugly IMO, so I recommend adding this CSS (or something similar):

```
.tags {
    max-width: 450px;
}
```

Which causes the tag list to wrap more gracefully:
[image: More graceful tags]

Since the `.tags` class already has `float: left`, this *might* have been the intended behavior, but I'm tagging this as a feature request rather than a bug because it's so minor.

**Update**

After playing around with a user style sheet, I realized that in 'mini' question lists, [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active), this tweak is not appropriate. The user style sheet I'm using right now is:

```
.tags { max-width: 450px; }
.narrow .summary .tags { max-width: none; }
```

Although there's probably a better way to do this.

Comment: @ColeJohnson SO uses a fixed-width layout, so it doesn't matter

Comment: @ColeJohnson I considered that. `.summary` has `width: 635px` and `.user-info` has `width: 185px`. So my 450 is just 635 - 185. Of course different style sheets / media queries might apply on different devices; this is just an initial suggestion.

Comment: **status-bydesign** - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212909/really-long-tags-push-user-info-down