# Really long tags push user info down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, questions, design

If really long tags are selected for a question, it pushes the user info down:

[image]

Windows 7
Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m

Wrapping the tags would look better:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a bug.

Comment: Yes, they do. Better than overlapping. How would you prefer it to be resolved?

Comment: If this is a bug then what would the correct behaviour be?

Comment: So you would prefer tags to go over or under username? Or maybe hide last tag? Hide username?..

Comment: I believe it is a bug. The tags should linebreak and start on a new line (like the favorite tags, for example). It's a matter of providing a `width:` to the tags' container.

Comment: I like @MadaraUchiha's idea, wrapping the tags would look a little better.

Comment: If this linebreak idea will be edited into question, I'll un-downvote it. I don't think I agree, but at least I can accept a bugreport that says a bit more than "current solution is bad".

Comment: @Mołot - Ok, updated.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: if "I think this should have been designed differently" counts as a bug where you work, I feel sorry for you! :)

Comment: @Wooble - Do you think this is more of a feature request then?  I can change the tag

Comment: @Wooble: A bug in web design means that it behaves awkwardly or unexpectedly. "Awkwardly" fits the bill here. You can call it however you want, but the current situation isn't optimal.

Comment: The suggested wrapping looks more awkward to me. But I wouldn't call the wrapped version a "bug" either if it were implemented. Although I might reach for a userscript to unwrap it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - that was the former behavior. It was changed.

Comment: Just found this question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196515/wrapping-long-tag-names-in-question-list?rq=1), looks like a duplicate.  Turns out I'm not the only one who thinks it looks bad :p