# Why are some user profile images showing up on the left side in the list of questions?

Tags: bug, design

User images have always been on the right side in this list, but to my surprise, today two images showed up on the left side:

[image: two images are showing up on the left side, whereas usually they all show up on the right]

I am using the desktop version of Google Chrome on Ubuntu.

**Is this a bug?**

Comment: *Is this a bug?* ... No, it is by design.

Comment: I closed it myself as a duplicate. **It does seem to be a bug though.** It wasn't like this before, and 2 questions about it have popped up here within 24 hours of each other.

Comment: It certainly happened in 2013: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212909/really-long-tags-push-user-info-down but I forgive you that you don't remember stuff from before you joined ....

Comment: @rene What? That's a link to a question that proves that **what I am saying is true** and **what you are saying is not**.

Comment: @rene https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366329/profile-images-are-pushed-to-next-line-if-tags-extend-too-far-to-the-right#comment1220839_366329

Comment: ***That  question is tagged status-bydesign*** ... ***I'm right*** ....

Comment: The comment I just pointed you to, says that there was a "miscommunication" and that "someone already pushed a fix for this before we'd even triaged it ;) It'll be live in the next build" ... If there's a "fix" then there must have been a bug in the first place.

Comment: I guess they didn't fancy to go over all the meta posts and comments and just called it *fixed* so we could all go on with our lifes.

Comment: I thought that by "fix" they meant that the images are going to go back to the right-side of the page, like they were in the 2013 example you showed me. Anyway, we will find out tomorrow :)