# Alignment issue for the last modified information in the "Top Questions" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-questions, indentation

In the [Top Questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (homepage), the **asked/modified X mins ago** text was left-aligned next to the tags. Previously the text was right-aligned. Seems some alignment issue introduced on that page recently.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: top questions]

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 89.0 (64-bit) |
| Google Chrome | 91.0.4472.101 (Official Build) (64-bit) |

**Update:** I see the same alignment issue in all other Stack Exchange site's "Top Questions" page too.

Comment: There was [this other, pretty related issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366329/908360) recently. The persistence of this kind of issues may suggest at a fragmented, hard-to-manage codebase: to me it seems like a proper overhaul and tidy-up of this component could be beneficial? While working as a dev, I used to like these tasks: hunting down pieces of code related to a component scattered around here and there, and unifying them in a tidied-up, canonical component definition... (Such refactors and tidy-ups are a kind of repaying technical debt: a normal part of developing any codebase.)

Comment: @Levente there is lack of testing, for sure. It is "Publish and let the users find the bugs" design.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard that is pretty much common in the industry. And we are cheap testers :) The only thing we (SO and us) could be concerned with is SO's reputation...

Comment: @Levente true. What bugs me here is that this one is **super trivial to see**. Nobody in the chain bothered to even take a look in the homepage during the process of publishing the changes, and this annoys me. They all just went ahead with the changes, approving them all the way to g̶l̶o̶r̶y̶ bugged homepage.

Comment: It also breaks the "Newest" on the questions page too, when there is too much space used by the tags.

Comment: It's not just on Meta.SE and it's not just the "Active" tab. The problem exists with most tabs on Stack Overflow, for example.

Comment: As I have [learned from @Luuklag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366481/alignment-issue-in-the-top-questions-page#comment1221160_366490), the new generation of this component is already in the works, as can be observed here: https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#layout-examples Apparently we just need to survive until the frontend gets migrated to the new framework.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Updates/creation info of a post on the Home page seems to be broken](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408400/4642212).

Comment: @Levente Don’t hold your breath. It’s been in the works for years, and likely will take further years before it will get live here.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alignment issue has been fixed.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Bug fixed]

Answer (score 10):

The breaking change was adding class named `tags` to the parent element of the tags, which has CSS rule `float: left;`.

Removing the float left rule from the `tags` class, or removing the class from the tags parent element would solve the issue.

Comment: The usercard class `class="started mt0"` that sits nested within has a `float: right;` property, but is overruled by the `tags` class.

Comment: Well, I would say in the first place, probably it could be beneficial trying to avoid _both_ _floats_ and _flexbox_ to manage the same layout...

Comment: @Levente meh, that's their choice, won't meddle in it. Just found the breaking change.

Comment: Regarding the code you pointed out in the answer: SO frontenders also could / should embrace the "[block, element, modifier](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/)" selector pattern, achieving control of what they are actually doing. Seeing this _generic selector_ with this massively impactful declaration on it: `.tags { float: left; }`, I can imagine that touching CSS on this project currently is a _nightmare_.

Comment: @Levente embracing BEM would be a huge regression.

Comment: In all fairness they are building a "design system", named [stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) Hopefully that will clear a lot of tech debt on the CSS side.

Comment: @Luuklag that's a very useful reveal! Here is the new generation of the same component (called "Post summary"), with as far as I can tell flawless responsive layout: https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/#layout-examples (also, it's using some consciously structured classnames). Looks like much of today's struggle is just keeping legacy code alive until migrating over to the new one becomes a possibility. This paints an entirely different picture!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed something similar [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/), but while in your screenshot at lest the names are visible, here we have a question with apparently no author at all (see screenshot below)! It seems in this case we only get the name appearing in the right place when the tags take up so much space that the username has to appear  on the next line:

[image]

As the comments on this thread's question suggest, the bug may be related to these MSE questions which were recently posed as bug reports:

- [Profile images are pushed to next line if tags extend too far to the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366329/391772)
- [Why are some user profile images showing up on the left side in the list of questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366409/391772)

Comment: Something else is happening here. The top highlighted question is by a deleted user, that is what sets it apart. The third question in your list also displays the author, while still being on the same line as the tags.

Comment: I can only reproduce this on one question and it was migrated and posted by a user who doesn't have an account on the linked site.

Comment: @user1271772 it is, because it is centred to the left, instead of the right.