# Eeek! Homepage view user details no longer float to the right

Tags: bug, design, homepage

[In the past](http://web.archive.org/web/20210612165921/https://meta.stackexchange.com/), the user details of the user who made the last activity used to float nicely to the right:

[image: user details floating to the right in the past]

However, now they don't:

[image: user details not floating to the right anymore]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: This was reported a short while ago: [Alignment issue in the "Top Questions" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366481/alignment-issue-in-the-top-questions-page) - But it has significantly less "Eeek!"

Comment: @Spevacus thanks! Somehow I missed it. *blush*

Comment: I also missed that one, maybe the title should be changed...

Comment: @10Rep yeah, well I added the [tag:homepage] tag, so searching by tag and keyword like "alignment" should work now.